# Replace string by values from collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner ini Laravel. I have this code:

```
    $value = "Szanowni Państwo,
    Status został zmieniony.
    <br/><br/>
    
    Osoba odp.: {osoba_odpowiedzialna}<br/>";
    
$collection = collect(
            (object) [
                'osoba_odpowiedzialna' => $responsiblePerson,
                'rodzaj' => data_get($term, 'termType.name'),
                'klient' => data_get($term, 'client.name'),
                'sprawa' => data_get($term, 'caseInstance.internal_signature'),
                'status' => data_get($term, 'termStatus.name'),
                'adres' => route('calendar.index')
            ]
        );
```

in result $collection I have:

https://ibb.co/Kz18CJ1

I need replace my $value - values from $collection by key: osoba_odpowiedzialna, klient, rodzaj etc.

How can I make it?

Comment: can you dd($collection['osoba_odpowiedzialna']) ?

Comment: I have result: Łukasz Moderator,  - it's okey

Comment: so you can do it with the rest as well :)

Comment: I need new $value with replaced {osoba_odpowiedzialna} to $collection-> osoba_odpowiedzialna . How can i mąkę it?

Comment: not sure now what do you want to archieve :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, sorry, but I think what you want is this:

```
$replacedText = preg_replace('/{osoba_odpowiedzialna}/', 
$collection['osoba_odpowiedzialna'], $value);

//this will yield (last line below)
//Osoba odp.: Łukasz Moderator
```

After your comments:

```
$collection->map(function($item, $key) use (&$value){  //$collection->each(.. should also be fine
  $value = preg_replace('/{'.$key.'}/', $item, $value);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, just put the code inside the loop. Be sure to save the replaced values.

Comment: Where do you want to loop? Through your `$collection`?. If you shared your exact scenario and the relevant code, I might be able to help further.

Comment: My string $ value has a lot of replacement tags and they are dynamic. Instead of 60 x: $ this-> view = preg_replace ('/ {xxxxxx} /', $ collection ['xxxxxx'], $ this-> view); - I wish it was somehow automatically replaced

Comment: I think about something like this: foreach ($collection as $key => $value)
        {
            if(isset($collection[$key])) {
                $this->view = preg_replace('/{'.$key.'}/', $collection[$key], $this->view);
            }
        } is ok solution?

Comment: You can most certainly do that.

Comment: Your code should work, but I have also added an example using the Laravel collection's map function.